# How to copy bytes from a specific offset in a file to another file at a specific offset?

Tags: c#, file-io

Would like the most efficient way of copying, say, 1MB from an offset in file 1 to the same or different offset in file 2. Is it possible to have multiple threads doing the reads and the writes at the same time safely?

To clarify, I of course want to handle file->file as stated. However I also want to have multiple threads reading from a network IO bound location (internet, etc..), and then reassemble those back into a single file locally. If it makes more sense that the write operation be single-threaded that is fine too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost certainly don't *want* multiple threads doing this - you're going to be IO-bound, and you don't want the overhead of the disk seeking all over the place.

I'd just do it in one thread:

- Open file 1 for reading
- Seek
- Open file 2 for writing
- Seek
- Repeatedly copy a buffer at a time (e.g. 32K) from one stream to the other.

You may find that some of the [`FileOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx) (e.g. `SequentialScan` for the reader) could make a difference.

EDIT: As noted in comments, it *may* be worth using two threads - one to read and one to write, particularly if you're using two separate drives. However, it's *also* possible that with the operating system automatically doing prefetching etc, that wouldn't be helpful. It would *certainly* complicate the code.

Do you have a target time for this operation? How fast does a *simple* implementation take compared with that target time? I definitely wouldn't venture into multiple threads or async operations until you've established how long the simple approach takes.

Comment: Actually, using two threads (one for reading and one for writing) makes a lot of sense if the input and output files are on different drives. Determining if they are on separate drives is a rather difficult problem, but if you know beforehand . . .

Comment: @Jim: Yes, will edit. Two threads *might* make sense - multiple threads reading and writing doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in my question. I of course want to handle file->file as stated, but I also want to handle a file copy from a network stream as well where the network can be really slow. Think of download accelerator type of applications where you can have multiple connections to a webserver reading a file, and then writing to a single file. Although in this case it might be fine just to have a single thread do the writes as well?

Comment: @esac, Why not to edit question? In case of reading from multiple streams using multiple threads would produce simpler code, but I'd recommend using one thread with asynchronous Read/Write operations instead.

Comment: @esac: If you're reading from a network then I'd definitely stick to a single thread - the data's going to keep coming across the network for the brief time that you spend writing to disk.

Comment: @esac: Splitting a download into multiple threads will normally only speed up a download if each thread has some sort of connection speed limit, either because the server doesn't have enough bandwidth to service every user at 100% of that user's capacity or because there is an artificial constraint.  It probably won't help (and could hurt) if there is only one user, or if every user makes use of this system.  In short, using extra threads is a way for a specific user to get more than his share of the bandwidth, but does not inherently provide any speed benefit.